# Excel VBA INSERT INTO statement using variables

Tags: excel, sql, ms-access, vba

I am using an SQL query to insert data from an excel worksheet into an Access database.  I put all the data that I want from the worksheet into variables:

```
rwyNumber = Range("b13").Value & Range("c13").Value
testDate = Range("b5").Value
testTime = Range("b6").Value
rwySide1 = Range("b14").Value
firstThird1 = Range("b28").Value
secondThird1 = Range("b29").Value
thirdThird1 = Range("b30").Value
averageFriction1 = Range("b23").Value
```

If I want to store testDate and testTime as Date/Time, do I need to convert them when I store them in the variable (above) or will access automatically make them a Date/Time as long as I have the data type set to Date/Time for those columns in the table?  Also with doubles and strings.

What is the correct syntax for the rest of my query:

```
stSQL1 = "INSERT INTO Friction Tests  (Runway Number, Runway Test Side, Test Date, Test Time, 1/3, 2/3, 3/3, Average)"
stSQL1 = "VALUES ( " ....
```

The table has an auto PK.  The first two values are strings, the next two are Date/Time, and the last four are doubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not make use of date/time field to include test time?

It is best to format dates, assuming that b5 is a date type:

```
testDate = Format(Range("b5").Value,"yyyy/mm/dd")
```

You will end up with text, but this is not important.

```
stSQL1 = "INSERT INTO [Friction Tests] ([Runway Number], [Runway Test Side], " _
& "[Test Date], [Test Time], [1/3], [2/3], [3/3], [Average]) " _
& "VALUES ( " & rwyNumber  & ",#" &  testDate   & "#,#" & testTime   _
& "#," & rwySide1   & "," & firstThird1 _
& "," & secondThird1   & "," & thirdThird1 _
& "," & averageFriction1 & ")"
```

If any of the fields are text, the value will have to be surrounded by single quotes or two double quotes, in a similar way to date and time.

I strongly recommend getting rid of spaces in field (column) and table names.

Comment: You will also need to put square brackets around the Friction Tests table name as it has a blank in the table name.

Comment: Thanks. Should testDate be data type Date?

Comment: rwyNumber is a string (e.g. 16L,34R).  Should it be VALUES ('" & rwyNumber & "' ....?

Comment: No, it should contain data in the format year, month, day. I usually use "yyyy/mm/dd", but "yyyy-mm-dd" is also good. I mention this above.

Comment: Yes, VALUES ('" & rwyNumber & "' . If there is any possibility that rwyNumber could contain a quote, eg 16L'34R, you need to replace it with two quotes, Replace(rwyNumber,"'","''")