# Insert Excel Cell values into an existing SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel VBA INSERT INTO statement using variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792399/excel-vba-insert-into-statement-using-variables)

I've just started learning a bit of VBA, I've managed to import data from a DB created in SQL Server just fine, now I'm trying to export data from Excel into the same DB.

The following works just fine:

```
Dim cnState As ADODB.Connection
Dim sSQL As String
Set cnState = New Connection
With cnState
.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
.ConnectionString = "server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Trusted_Connection=Yes; database=SIM_PROJ"
.Open
End With
sSQL = "Insert Into Alunos Values ('3', 'Tiago Aleixo', 'Rua dos Pincéis' , '1990-05-26' , 'M' , 'Multimédia' , 'D')"
cnState.Execute sSQL

End Sub

Private Sub btn_goMenu_Click()

Sheet1.Select
```

The only issue is, I've only managed to figure out how to insert actual values through the code, I want to be able to read a whole line in Excel and insert it into my DB.

Something like this:

```
sSQL = "Insert Into Alunos Values (Range(A4).Value, Range(B4).Value, Range(C4).Value, Range(D4).Value, Range(E4).Value, Range(F4).Value, Range(G4).Value)"
```

IE, I only want values from line 4 to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to build the string more incrementally like:

```
  SQL = "INSERT INTO alunos VALUES ('" + Range(A4).Value + "', '" + Range(A5).Value + "', '"...
```

The syntax you show looks ilke it would try to insert the string "Range(A4).Value" into the database.

Comment: I've tried the following: 
`sSQL = "Insert Into Alunos Values ('" + Range("A3").Value + "' , '" + Range("B3").Value + "' , '" + Range("C3").Value + "' , '" + Range("D3").Value + "' , '" + Range("E3").Value + "' , '" + Range("F3").Value + "' , '" + Range("G3").Value + "')"`
But get a:
Type Mismatch error, could this be due to me trying to insert a date into the DB?...

Comment: Yes, that seems likely.  Try just doing a couple columns as a test, columns that are just plain old numbers or string.  Excel stores the date as an integer.  I'm not sure how you call the regular excel features thru VBA, but see what you get if you try TEXT(Range(A3),"yyyy-mm-dd"), something like that.  You want it to make a string that SQL Server will accept as a date, and I think that probably values with your locale, but the yyyy-mm-dd looks like it matches your example.

Comment: [Here's a link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/callingworksheetfunctionsinvba.aspx) about calling worksheet functions (like TEXT) from excel.

Answer (score 0):

Save your file as comma delimited CSV file and then you can use bulk insert as below.

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = "BULK INSERT Alunos FROM '"+@File+"' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',') "
exec (@sql)
```